# Publishing Azure function with custom python packages for App Service Plan Function app

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, publish

I am new to Azure functions. I have a python function on my local system with azure.storage.blob imported. When I try to publish it directly from Visual Studio Code I get the error this cannot be build and use --build-native-deps. For this I opened Azure CLI but I am not sure where to keep my code on Azure cloud in this to be published.

Appreciate all the help in advance.

This worked with functions with consumption plan. But when I try to do the same with App Service Plan I have created this does not work. When I run
`func azure functionapp publish remote-gc-copy --build remote`

I just get Remote Build Successful but doesn't publish.

[image: output of above command]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use func azure functionapp publish command

```
func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME> --build remote
```

First you need to create a resource group and a storage account. You can do it on Azure portal or by Azure CLI command.
Here are the commands if you want to use Azure CLI.

```
az group create --name myResourceGroup --location westeurope
```

```
az storage account create --name <storage_name> --location westeurope --resource-group myResourceGroup --sku Standard_LRS
```

Second you need to create your azure function app:

```
az functionapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --os-type Linux --consumption-plan-location westeurope  --runtime python --name <APP_NAME> --storage-account  <STORAGE_NAME>
```

The func azure functionapp publish is Azure Functions Core Tools command, so you need to install Azure Functions Core Tools command before that, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools) tutorial to install it. And then in your powershell connect to your Azure account(if you use rm command: Connect-AzureRmAccount), navigate to your python dir and run the func azure functionapp publish command(shown as below)

[image]

For further information, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python#deploy-the-function-app-project-to-azure) tutorial.

By the way, Azure function just support 3.6.x version of python, so if you install python 3.7 it may cause the error when you publish it from vs code to azure.